# How to update the applicationbadge number when application is not running in ios 7?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

my aps dictionary as under

```
{
aps =     {
    alert = "My first push notification!";
    "content-available" = 1;
    sound = default;
};
```

}

i have update badge count in following methode

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler
```

when application is running it is working fine.but when i kill my app and then after killing of app  i am trying to send push-notification.i received push notification on notification bar,but my badge number is not update.
 for updating badge my code is as under.

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler
{
   [AppCommon saveToUserDefaults:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[AppCommon readFromUserDefaultsForKey:@"bagecount"] intValue] + 1] forKey:@"bagecount"];
    int count = [[AppCommon readFromUserDefaultsForKey:@"bagecount"] intValue];
    NSLog(@"Set Badge %d",count);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: count];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should put the badge info within the notification payload like this:

```
{
aps =     {
    alert = "My first push notification!";
    "content-available" = 1;
    "badge" : 1
    sound = default;
};
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for give reply. Can i manage badge count from my application? i don't wants take badge count from server-side.

Comment: Yes you can manage the badge count on the client side. Use this delegate method `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` to implement your logic and not the one with the background fetch you are using.

Comment: i have already use above methode but i have issue. when i kill my app and then after killing of app i am trying to send push-notification.i received push notification on notification bar,but my badge number is not update.